# Examples of apps in the Mac App Store not made with objective-c/c/c++?

Tags: development, mac-appstore, cocoa

Are there any apps in the store made using mono, ruby or lisp or put together in another alternative way.

Do you know of any?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm already making apps using cocoa/objective-c, and I really love ruby and obscure languages.

Comment: There really are no restrictions on MAS build tools or embedding interpreters like the iOS store. The main rule seems to be it must be better than the alternatives already on the store from a UI polish and not require admin privileges to run. Good luck getting your ruby/alternative app in the MAS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [Briquette](http://briquetteapp.com/) is written in MacRuby and [made it into the MAS](http://twitter.com/#!/briquetteapp/status/66166095169585152), so it looks like there is at least one alternative to Objective-C for MAS apps.

Comment: ok, so ruby is possible. Great to hear. Are there other cool ruby apps out there?

Comment: How to submit your MacRuby app to the Mac App Store: http://astonj.com/tech/how-to-submit-your-macruby-app-to-the-mac-app-store/

Comment: More examples of MacRuby apps: http://redwoodapp.posterous.com/can-a-macruby-app-be-on-the-mac-app-store-yes

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that [Crush the Castle](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/crush-the-castle/id318639200?mt=8) used some sort of Flash-to-ObjC converter.

Answer (score 0):

[This app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eventclock/id403026288?mt=12#) is a QT app according to [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-35967.html), so QT is ok I in the MAS I guess.

However this doesn't shed any light on wether alternative languages are allowed in the MAS.

Answer (score 0):

[QuickAlarm](http://macdevshop.com/blog_posts/9-QuickAlarm-a-new-Alarm-Clock-for-the-Macintosh) was primarily written in MacRuby along with some Objective C routines.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of [electron applications](https://wiredelta.com/10-most-popular-electron-apps-2019/). WhatsApp is in the Mac App store, for example.

Perhaps it isn't in as an obscure programming language as you might have been thinking of but nonetheless, Electron is an option other than Objective-C or Swift.